# VBA: Change dot with comma and comman with dot in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Probably is very simple, But I'm in a hurry.

```
Public Sub StergeSTorOR()
Dim oRow As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = Selection(Selection.Count).Row To Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row Step -1

        For j = Selection(Selection.Count).Column To Selection.Cells(1, 1).Column Step -1
```

****How cand I loop over the value of the cell and change the , with . and vice-versa in the same time**

```
        Next j

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub